# Chrome Developer Tool is not showing responsiveness

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am having issues while checking responsiveness of my website on chrome developer tool. When I resize my chrome window, It shows responsivness

In the following image chrome window width is 768px

[image: resize window image]

But when I use `Toggle Device Toolbar` in chrome it does not show responsiveness as in the following image. The width is 768px.

[image: devtool]

My **index.html** file is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Personal Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/tab.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/mobile.css">
</head>
<body>
All the Code lies here
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS files are as follows

**style.css**

```
All the styles are here no media queries
```

**tab.css**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 501px)
{
All the styles are here
}
```

**mobile.css**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px)
{
All the styles are here
}
```

Comment: Add this tag to head - <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the Viewport tag in your head,

Add this to your `head` tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Please visit this [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) for more information

Comment: I didn't know viewport tag meaning util I got this issue, Great thanks!